# gevent, ways of triggering the newly-spawn tasks to run

Tags: python, thrift, gevent

my project is using gevnet, which is new to me, to implement a thrift server.

I am reading the code and learning from its document. The code snippet below is in my project:

```
TSocket.socket = gevent.socket # I find this when comparing the production
                               # code and mine. It seems that this socket
                               # schedule the tasks when there are newly-spawn ones. 
                               # Could someone tell me more about it?

while True:
    try:
        client = self.serverTransport.accept()
        gevent.spawn(self._serve_client, client)
    except (SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt):
        break
    except Exception as x:
        logging.exception(x)
```

After spawning, it directly finishes it work here.

But in my own implementation, which is for self-learning, i have to do the following:

```
while True:
    try:
        client = self.serverTransport.accept()
        gevent.spawn(self._serve_client, client)
        gevent.sleep(0)  # switch to the newly-spawn task.
                         # this makes it to process tasks one by one and
                         # this makes it non-concurrent
    except (SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt):
        break
    except Exception as x:
        logging.exception(x)
```

In my production code, i haven't found any clue of how to trigger the tasks to run. 
So I am asking here for some light on the ways of running newly-spawn tasks in a server above.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have to call `gevent.sleep(0)` because nothing else
triggers the gevent loop. Having this sleep gives control back to
gevent, which executes the spawned greenlet.

The line `TSocket.socket = gevent.socket` in the production code patches the
default thrift socket implementation to use
a gevent socket instead; gevent sockets run the gevent loop, so you really
need this patch for your code to run.

Without the patch, `TSocket.socket` is blocking and kills concurrency
(without OS-level threads).

Comment: You mean that, after the code patch, gevent.socket will monitor the gevent loop. Once there is one newly-spawn greenlet, it will schedule it to run?

Comment: Not exactly. I mean that as long as the gevent socket is "active", i.e. it is receiving or sending data, the gevent loop will run. So for example if a socket is blocked on a receive call and you spawn a new greenlet it will be scheduled, otherwise not.

Comment: In your example, the socket is reviecing data, i.e. a spawned greenlet is reciecing data. According to my understanding to gevent, the IO operation will make greenlets switch. If at this time, a new greenlet is about to spawn. Then after its spawning, the gevent will switch to the new greenlet immediately. Am I right here?

Comment: After the spawning, greenlet is scheduled to run. Next time the gevent loop runs it will probably be executed, but it's not 100% sure, if the loop is ran only once for example there might be other pending tasks...